# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException when trying to parse Date/Time in json

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using RestTemplete to get json data from a rest api and I'm using Gson to parse data from json format to Object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

List<Appel> resultList = null;

resultList = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(urlService, Appel[].class));
```

but I get this problem with Date, what should I do ..

```
Could not read JSON: 1382828400000; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1382828400000
```

my Pojo that contains other pojos in it's body

```
public class Appel implements Serializable {

    private Integer numOrdre;
    private String reference;
    private String objet;
    private String organisme;
    private Double budget;
    private Double caution;
    private Date dateParution;
    private Date heureParution;
    private Date dateLimite;
    private Date heureLimite;
    private List<Support> supportList;
    private Ville villeid;
    private Categorie categorieid;

    public Appel() {
    }

    public Appel(Integer numOrdre, String reference, String objet, String organisme, Date dateParution, Date heureParution, Date dateLimite) {
        this.numOrdre = numOrdre;
        this.reference = reference;
        this.objet = objet;
        this.organisme = organisme;
        this.dateParution = dateParution;
        this.heureParution = heureParution;
        this.dateLimite = dateLimite;
    }
```

this is ths json returned by my API

```
[
   {
       "numOrdre": 918272,
       "reference": "some text",
       "objet": "some text",
       "organisme": "some text",
       "budget": 3000000,
       "caution": 3000000,
       "dateParution": 1382828400000,
       "heureParution": 59400000,
       "dateLimite": 1389657600000,
       "heureLimite": 34200000,
       "supportList":
       [
           {
               "id": 1,
               "nom": "some text",
               "dateSupport": 1384732800000,
               "pgCol": "013/01"
           },
           {
               "id": 2,
               "nom": "some text",
               "dateSupport": 1380236400000,
               "pgCol": "011/01"
           }
       ],
       "villeid":
       {
           "id": 2,
           "nom": "Ville",
           "paysid":
           {
               "id": 1,
               "nom": "Pays"
           }
       },
       "categorieid":
       {
           "id": 1,
           "description": "some text"
       }
   },
  .....
]
```

Comment: What does your json look like? What does your pojo look like?

Comment: You are trying to cast a long into date.

Comment: Those values, `1384732800000`, seem like timestamps. Gson is not setup to parse dates with timestamps. You'll have to configure it with a custom `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: You need to use GsonBuilder and pass the date formatter string so Gson knows how to parse your date.  Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34187419/1103584

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I've done finally is going to my API project and create a CustomSerializer

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {  

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(t);

        jg.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

that return the format yyyy-MM-dd and I annotated date fields with

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
```

in my Android application I created Gson object as

```
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            appels = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(reader, Appel[].class));
            content.close();
```

and it works for now .. thanks for your help I appreciate it

Comment: Where to write this @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)

Comment: It's no longer necessary to create a Custom Serializer.  See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34187419/1103584

Answer (score 12):

Custom Serializers are no longer necessary - simply use GsonBuilder, and specify the date format, as such:

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

String json = new GsonBuilder()
               .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S")
               .create()
               .toJson(t);

System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `1382828400000` value is a long (time in milliseconds). You are telling `GSON` that the field is a `Date`, and it cannot automatically convert a `long` into a `Date`.

You have to specify your fields as long values

```
private long dateParution;
private long heureParution;
private long dateLimite;
private long heureLimite;
```

and after `GSON` casts the JSON string to the desired `Appel` class instance, construct another object with those fields as Dates and convert them while assigning the values to the new object.

**Another alternative** is to implement your own Custom Deserializer:

```
 public class CustomDateDeserializer extends DateDeserializer {
     @Override
     public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         // get the value from the JSON
         long timeInMilliseconds = Long.parseLong(jsonParser.getText());

         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMilliseconds);
         return calendar.getTime();
     }
 }
```

You have to set this custom deserializer on your desired fields, on the setter methods, like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomDateDeserializer.class)
public void setDateParution(Date dateParution) {
    this.dateParution = dateParution;
}
```